# How to install Synfig Studio in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, synfig-studio

I have seen a presentation with vector animations made in Synfig Studio, but there is not such in my repository. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is your solution**

- Download latest version `.deb` file for Ubuntu from [Synfig Studio Site](http://www.synfig.org/cms/)

  - [Download 32 bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synfig/files/binaries/linux-binaries/synfigstudio_0.64.0-20130509.master.8_i386.deb/download)
  - [Download 64 bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synfig/files/binaries/linux-binaries/synfigstudio_0.64.0-20130509.master.8_amd64.deb/download)
- Go to your directory where it is downloaded. Usually it would be in `Downlaods` of user account.

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  ```
- Install it using `gdebi` you can also install using `dpkg` but `gdebi` is preferred. (eg. for [32 bit package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synfig/files/binaries/linux-binaries/synfigstudio_0.64.0-20130509.master.8_i386.deb/download))

  ```
  sudo gdebi synfigstudio_0.64.0-20130509.master.8_i386.deb
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i synfigstudio_0.64.0-20130509.master.8_i386.deb
  ```
- Thats it..

Reply if you need further assistance..

Comment: All worked perfectly, thanx

Comment: Sounds good.. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply download synfig studio by typing this to your command line:
    `$`sudo apt-get update
    `$`sudo apt-get install synfigstudio

Comment: currently it is possible. In time of the question studio was not in the repos.

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile the software is provided as an .appimage. This can be run directly using

```
chmod a+x synfigstudio-<version>.appimage
./synfigstudio-<version>.appimage
```

Enjoy!